# Need to compare two Strings treating as list of String elements in drool

Tags: java, drools, dsl, mvel

I have a java.util.Map object which has String values. I need to compare one of the String value of java.util.Map to myString value. Below are variables with values to understand problem better.

```
myMap[STATE.code]="AK","MI","GA","NY","OH","CA"

myString="MI","OH"
```

NOTE: ("AK","MI","GA","NY","OH","CA") and ("MI","OH") are complete string values and not a comma separated values.

I need to figure out that whether any of "MI" or "OH" is present in "AK","MI","GA","NY","OH","CA". 
Hence I am treating myString and myMAp[STATE.code] value as 'elements of list' and try to compare both. I tried Collections.disjoint function to find out is there any common element in the list.

In DSL :

```
[condition][]Putting codes into variable=$code : String(this == myMap[STATE.code]) 

[condition][]Codes exist in list {myString}= Boolean( java.util.Collections.disjoint(java.util.Arrays.asList($code) , java.util.Arrays.asList({myString}) ) == false )

[condition][]Codes doesn't exist in list {myString}= not( Boolean ( java.util.Collections.disjoint(java.util.Arrays.asList($clientCatCode) , java.util.Arrays.asList({myString}) ) == false ))
```

Although DSL successfully compiled but there is no decision coming out of it and nor any exception or error. Seems that this approach is not correct. Can anyone suggest me any approach or help in correcting my DSL.

Comment: I suggest that you write and post a compilable and executable piece of Java code where you have the "my" Map object with two or three elements and one or two "my" String objects. Then, we can agree on the (Java) code that says true or false when a Map is combined with a String. This done, we can begin to discuss Drools. And, finally, we can talk about a sensible DSL.

Answer (score 0):

If the state codes are Key in the map, we can check if the given String is present in the Map or not by checking map.containsValue(String),

if it's Map value we get can it through map.containsKey(String);

Comment: STATE.code is a key in map (some constant) which hold value ("AK","MI","GA","NY","OH","CA").

Comment: If I compare myString using map.containsValue(), then the result will be always false. Since myString is ("MI","OH") and this is partially match with value of map.  Also myString can have random sequence of code which will may or may not match with the sequence of map value.

Comment: so the myString is an array? and map values are taken as you are comparing both the arrays as object? I am not clear of the question